# Azure Data factory - parent pipeline and child pipeline to execute parallely

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

A parent pipeline has a lookup and foreach. Inside foreach there is child(execute pipeline1 activity). Child pipeline has lookup and foreach again.
I want the parent pipelines foreach activity to run parallely , but currently it is running sequentially(I have unchecked the sequential option). Child pipeline activities in foreach is running parallely which is fine.
How can I make the parent pipeline foreach activity to execute parallely.
Parent pipeline as below.and the execute pipeline1 waiting till the previous execute pipeline1 finishes. How to make the execute pipeline1 to run parallely.
[image]

below is the activities in execute pipeline1
[image]

Answer (score 2):

To run *execute pipeline1 activity* in parallel, apply the following settings in the pipeline:

- In the **parent pipeline's foreach activity**, uncheck the sequential box if it is checked.

[image]

- Similarly, in the *execute pipeline1 activity* which is inside the foreach activity of the parent pipeline, uncheck the *Wait on completion* checkbox.

[image].

This will help you to run the activities simultaneously.

Comment: As you said the sequential checkbox for parent pipeline foreach is not enabled(Issequential is false). wait on completion is unchecked as well. But still the parent pipeline activity is not running parallely.

Comment: Can you please check the comment  and let me know the why this unexpected behavior of pipeline happens.

Comment: How are you running the pipeline? debug or trigger